# Does execfile() open and/or close file in Python?

Tags: python, io, fifo, execfile

I have three files: `myfifo.py` which is named-pipe, `writer.py`:

```
path = "myfifo.py"
fifo = open(path)

for i in range(1,4):
  fifo.write( "print %d" % i )

fifo.close()
```

and `reader.py`:

```
path = "myfifo.py"

execfile(path)
```

If I execute the reader-file `./reader.py` and then - the writer (in other terminal) `./writer.py` I get the expected result:

```
1
2
3
```

But why it works?

**Question**: Does `execfile` open `myfifo.py`? And does it close it? What practice is recommended here? I mean should I close the `FiFo` in both client and server files?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What is the behaviour you expect? What happens? How do they differ? etc.

Comment: I think my question(s) are clear. `FiFo` (as I know) is allowed to be used iff both ends (writer and reader) use it. So my question is If program is working then *Does `execfile()` open file?* And if so how to close file after execution?

Comment: Well. The thing is, the clarity of a given question depends on whether other people, rather than you, think it's clear. It seems obvious that `execfile` has to open the file otherwise it can't possibly work. Is that what you're asking? Or something else?

Comment: Does it close file after execution process?

Comment: Is there some reason you think it wouldn't? You can trivially `strace` it to check.